# Windows 8 App: Why must I specify ms-appx:/// in my image source URL?

Tags: windows-8

I've been looking at the [XAML Images sample project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9) and the XAML to load an image in that sample looks like this:

```
<Image Source="Assets/image1.jpg"/>
```

However, in my own project I find that I cannot load any images like that.  If I try I get E_NETWORK_ERROR when I handle the ImageFailed. Instead, I discovered that I have to use the ms-appx:/// prefix like this:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/image1.jpg"/>
```

Then it works.  Any ideas what's different about my project vs the sample that would cause this?

Comment: Is your xaml in a folder of its own?  Image references are relative, so if you are starting in a folder you need to leave it by doing `..` first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried "`<Image Source="/Assets/image1.jpg>`"?

Comment: It was just because my xaml file was in a sub directory.  I assumed the paths were relative to the project root for some reason.  I'm dumb.

Answer (score 2):

M working on Windows phone 8 at i used this.

OrderImage1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("///Assets/images/order_bread.png"));

Answer (score 1):

[This behavior works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) - tested in Windows 8 RTM / Visual Studio 2012 RTM, and can confirm that the ms-appx:// prefix is not required. What builds are you using?

There might be an issue with how you are setting the image or what Build Action you are selecting for it.

Also, this is documented at [How to load file resources (XAML) (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322(v=win.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For declarative images you do not  need the ms-appx namespace (images declared in XAML). For dynamic databound images, a new bitmap instance is created, and it requires this namespace.

A great way to tackle this is to derive your data objects from a base object that implements the namespace as a shared property:

```
Private Shared _baseUri As New Uri("ms-appx:'''")

'//image handling
Private _image As ImageSource
Private _imagePath As String
Public Property Image As ImageSource
    Get
        If Me._image Is Nothing AndAlso Me._imagePath IsNot Nothing Then
            Me._image = New BitmapImage(New Uri(dataModelBase._baseUri, Me._imagePath))
        End If
        Return Me._image
    End Get

    Set(value As ImageSource)
        Me._imagePath = Nothing
        Me.SetProperty(Me._image, value)
    End Set
End Property
```