# Image Binding to string

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am unable to display the image which is in this location Resources/Images/abc.png.

Here is what i am doing:

```
public class A
    {
private string image;
public string Image
        {
            get { return image; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.image)
                {
                    image = value;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

In my .CS file:

```
if (somecondition)
                    {
                        a.Image = @"Resources/Images/abc.png";
                    }
```

In my XAML file:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="TopicDataTemplate" >
<Image Stretch="None" 
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Source="{Binding Image}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But its not displaying the image, how to fix this ? What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: what  you  mean by  ressources  is it a folder or app  resources

Comment: There is folder called Resources by default that where i have added the images

Comment: Your `Image` property lacks a property change notification mechanism. Consider implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in your class A.

Comment: @Clemens he  does not this for the first  binding

Comment: Your image must be set as Embedded resource then you can call Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream method. the following article show you the way 
http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/how-load-image-set-embedded

Comment: can you tell us the absolute path of your images resources

Comment: @Clemens how is it related to displaying the image ?

Comment: @alnaji This is a data template and that why i cannot get a reference of the image name in the CS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image path should be ok, provided that there actually is a file named `abc.png` in a folder named `Images` in another folder named `Resources` in your Visual Studio project, and that its *Build Action* is set to `Resource` (which is the default).

**Update** I'm not sure if the above is also true for Windows Phone. I guess that the default conversion from string to ImageSource might not be as capable on that platform as it is in WPF.

---

However, on either platform, if you want to change the `Image` property during runtime, you need to implement a property change mechanism that notifies the data binding that the `Image` property has changed. One way is to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in your class A:

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string image;
    public string Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously it is also necessary that the `Image` binding is properly set up, i.e. that the `DataContext` of the templated item holds a reference to an instance of class A.

Comment: Still No change, its not displaying the image from location Resources/Images/abc.png

Comment: Did you set the binding source object propely, i.e. the DataContext of the templated control or item?

Comment: And you might have to add the [`ms-appx` Uri prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx) to your image path. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12764376/1136211), too.

Comment: @Clemens My bad - it should also work with string as I've tested it (I've to update my information). Sorry for confusion. And I think OP asks about WP as he added this tag.